# PHP not worked in IIS server 8 on server 2012?

Tags: php, iis, webserver, windows-server-2012

I am using IIS to run my php code on my computer. I use PHP binary file from php.net as people described on IIs.net.

I have configure everything but it's show me a error. How I can fix it.

Can someone help me on this. Actually I use IIS8 and I am not sure how to fix it on Server 2012.

simple php file gave me this error

> PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php on line 1

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone =  "Asia/Delhi"

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
date.default_latitude = 6.116667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
date.default_longitude = 106.650002

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

**the problem is  I have read on blog "Asia/Delhi" which is invalid. change to "Asia/Calcutta" work** fine for 5.4.

Thanks for solve my issue.

Comment: Did you actually read the 'error'? It's not an error - it's a warning, and tells you exactly what you have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a value into your php.ini file.

For example, here is mine :

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

Comment: @user1377045 Asia/Delhi does not exists. Asia timezones are in the php documentation (which is linked in the setting comment) http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Comment: yes, I have made it fixed. I have confused by a comment in PHp.net website. Change to Asia/Calcutta made it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1377045 If the answer is the one you were looking for, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the icon next to the vote counter